# Is there a programmatic way to decide if API Platform can access updates to an Entity?

Tags: api-platform.com

I have an entity called Report.
On Report, I have a status field.

```
class Report
{
    private $status;

    const STATUS_DRAFT = 1;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 2;
    const STATUS_ARCHIVED = 3;
}
```

What I'd like to do is when Report report has a status of archived, to stop any more updates happening.

What would be the best strategy?

- Custom Controller
- Validation Groups
- Listener/Subscriber

Or is there something else I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best strategy depends on your philosophy and the permissions on your app.

The most native way is to implement the [`security_post_denormalize`](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/#executing-access-control-rules-after-denormalization) attribute, but that implies that the current user must be authenticated.:

```php
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     ...
 *
 *     itemOperations = {
 *          "get",
 *          "put" = {
 *              "security_post_denormalize" = "previous_object.getStatus() !== constant('App\\Entity\\Report::STATUS_ARCHIVED')",
 *              "security_message" = "You can't update this report because it is archived."
 *          }
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ReportRepository::class)
 */
class Report
```

Otherwise, if you're NOT using the GraphQl system, the `previous_object` is accessible from the current `Request`:

```php
$previousObject = $request->get('previous_data');
if ($previousObject->getStatus() === Report::STATUS_ARCHIVED) {
    // abort
}
```

Given that, you can implement any service you want. I don't think there is a better choice among those you enumerated. It's up to you.